# Alamofire public key pinning not validating other url

Tags: swift, ssl-certificate, alamofire, certificate-pinning

I have a 3 `baseURL` these 3 are having different ssl certificate, I have downloaded one certificate and hardcoded in Xcode project even if I change the `url` request the app not blocks the request.

I am using this class

```
class APIManager {

    static let sharedInstance = APIManager()
    private var manager : SessionManager?
    func sessionManager() -> SessionManager {

        if let manage = self.manager {
            return manage
        }
        else {
            let serverTrustpolicies: [ String: ServerTrustPolicy] = ["url" : .pinPublicKeys(publicKeys: ServerTrustPolicy.publicKeys(), validateCertificateChain: true, validateHost: true)
            ]

            self.manager = SessionManager(
                serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustpolicies)
            )
            let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
            configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30
            self.manager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
            return self.manager!
        }

    }
}

APIManager.sharedInstance.sessionManager().upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData)
}
```

Can anyone explain to implement ?

Answer (score 0):

You must explicitly set `ServerTrustPolicy` values for every host you want to validate. So when you create your policies dictionary, you need to pass every host.

```
let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = ["url" : .pinPublicKeys(publicKeys: ServerTrustPolicy.publicKeys(), validateCertificateChain: true, validateHost: true)]
```

This should have your other base URLs added, with the appropriate policy set.

Comment: Thanks for your time. The problem i did is i have not compared the two pins (local pin and server certificate pin) means alamofire will not compare the both public pin automatically we should compare the key manually and based on the result we can make decision. I wrote a custom delegate session for alamofire to compare and it worked as expected.